# Copy row to another sheet on Google Sheets based on criteria and cell value and if status changes on one sheet, entire row is changed in second sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am able to copy some row values from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on a criteria and a cell value where when [Qualification] = 'Qualified' and, if [No of positions] = 1 then the values from specific columns are copied once, and if [No of positions] = 2 then the values are copied twice to Sheet 2.

However, I would like that if [No of positions] on Sheet 1 reduces by 1 for example, then one entire row on Sheet 2 is deleted.
With the current query, if [No of positions] in Sheet one reduces by 1, only the values copied to Sheet 2 are deleted. This creates a mismatch if data has been inputted in subsequent cells on the same row.

Below is an example.

Sheet1

| Lead Type | Lead ID | Company Name | Employment Type | No of positions | Qualification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | B21 | KidRed Co. | Full Time | 1 | Not Qualified |
| Africa | B24 | Freddie Co. | Part Time | 2 | Qualified |
| Base | B35 | Akila Co. | Full Time | 1 | Qualified |
| External | B40 | SeeQue Co. | Part Time | 1 | Not Qualified |

This is what i get initially. (The bold are subsequent values input in the new sheet)

Sheet2

| Lead ID | Company Name | Qualification | **Partner Name** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified | **Sharon** |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified | **Kerubo** |
| B35 | Akila Co. | Qualified | **Sandra** |

This is what happens if I update the [Lead ID] 'B24' [No of positions] to 1.

Sheet2

| Lead ID | Company Name | Qualification | **Partner Name** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified | **Sharon** |
| B35 | Akila Co. | Qualified | **Kerubo** |
| (blank) | (blank) | (blank) | **Sandra** |

[Partner Name] 'Kerubo' should also have been deleted.

What I have managed to do so far, with the help of one of the Stackoverflow stars is is use the following query

```
const SAMPLE = v => v.flatMap(([A,B,C,D,E,F]) => E > 0 && F == "Qualification" ? [...Array(E)].fill([B,C,F]) : []);
```

Please assist.

P.S I am new to using Google Sheets. Please assist.

Comment: @Tanaike please see above.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have 3 questions in your question. 1. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic for achieving `[Partner Name] 'Kerubo' should also have been deleted.`. Can I ask you about the detailed logic of this? 2. I cannot understand `The bold are subsequent values input in the new sheet`. Can I ask you about the detail of this? 3. In your current situation, how do you obtain your 2nd table in your question?

Comment: @Tanaike Please don't apologize. I understand.

1. Once the [No of position] for Lead Type [B24]  is changed to 1 (originally it was 2), what happens to the sheet is that the values copied are the only ones deleted, not the entire row. 
Here is the logic: 
If [No of positions] = 2, then 2 rows should be created first, then the columns B,C,F to be copied. 
If [No of positions] is updated to 1, then the whole second row should be deleted.
What is happening is that only the copied values are deleted.

Comment: @Tanaike 
2. I made the values bold to show that more data is added to that Sheet AFTER (B,C,F) are copied from Sheet 1. 

3. Currently, the second table is gotten from the script above. If the criteria is met, the values (B,C,F) are copied to Sheet 2. The I continue to add more data.
If you try it on your side, you may see visually what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Its okay.@Tanaike, kindly assist whenever you can.